# Continuity of $ f(x,y)=\frac{x^{3}y}{x^{6}+y^{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I am supposed to determine if function: 
$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^{3}y}{x^{6}+y^{2}},&(x,y)\neq(0,0)\\
0,&(x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}
$$ is continous on $\left ( 0,0 \right )$.

What I did: I substitute $y=x^{3}$:

$\lim_{\left ( x,y \right )\rightarrow \left ( 0,0 \right )}\frac{x^{3}y}{x^{6}+y^{2}}=\lim_{ x \rightarrow  0}\frac{x^{6}}{x^{6}+x^{6}}=\frac{1}{2}$

But I  do not know what to do next, I know that it is not continous, so that limit should does not exist.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $y=mx^3$. Then, the limit becomes $\frac{m}{1+m^2}$, which depends on $m$. Thus the function is discontinuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Okay, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Since $\lim_{x\to0}f(x,0)=0$, it follows (together with what you did) that $f$ has no limit at $(0,0)$. So, whatever is the way that you define $f(0,0)$, $f$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you so much